# customise the mpmediapickercontroller

Tags: ios, mpmediapickercontroller

I want to use the mpmediapickercontroller and not create my own custom media picker ,but I have three issues. Any help appreciated.

1.When the song is selected in the MPMediaPicker, how can we unselect the song.
2.Can we allow the user to select a category like artist, album and playlist and then start playing whole of that category.
3.How can I provide the shuffle option with in the MpMedia Picker over the "All songs" category.

Thanks.

Comment: I have the exact same problems... did you find a solution ?